# UI accdb gets corrupted on access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have migrated an Access application (for a client of mine) from Access 2003 to Access 2010. This means:

- The application was composed of a set of 4 "UI" databases accessing 2 "data" databases.
- All 6 databases were in Access 2002/2003 `.mdb` format
- All 6 databases were and are still located on a CIFS network share.
- We migrated all 4 "UI" databases to Access 2010 `.accdb` format.
- We left both "data" databases in their original format.
- The data tables are linked through standard Access "linked tables" mechanism. (No ODBC or such)

The problem my client is facing is that the UI database becomes corrupted on a regular basis, the error message being something like "The input expression contains a function name that Microsoft Access cannot find". It is preceded by a proposal to repair the file, which has been damaged.

I am suspecting some user action to interrupt the program due to poor responses time of Access 2010, but if it turns out not to be the case, the question is: Is there a known problem with the `accdb` file format located on a network share?

Answer (score 1):

I found most of my issues occur when everyone uses the same "UI"/front end databases.  I modified a vbs script that makes a copy of the front end database to a local drive and use that instead of the original.

Wasn't able to find the link to the original script.  Here is my version of the script.

```
Option Explicit

Dim objShell
Dim objFSO
Dim strHomeFolder
Dim strFullPath
Dim strDestinationFolder
Dim strDestinationFullPath
Dim returnValue

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strHomeFolder = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%")

strFullPath = "\\networkPathToOriginalDatabase"
strDestinationFolder = strHomeFolder & "\myFolderName"
strDestinationFullPath = strDestinationFolder & "\myDataBaseName"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
returnValue = 0

If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strDestinationFolder) Then
    returnValue = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDestinationFolder)
End If

returnValue = objFSO.CopyFile(strFullPath, strDestinationFullPath, True)

' open the front end
objShell.Run """" & strDestinationFullPath & """", 1, false

' cleanup
Set objShell = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

Here are also some general Access practices (there is a section on corruption)

http://allenbrowne.com/tips.html